# LeJOS GyroSensor sample always 0

Tags: java, lejos-nxj, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I would like to read the current angle from my Ev3GyroSensor, however the returned value is always 0.
I tested multiple Ports nothing worked.
If I test the sensor with the LeJOS integrated Tool, everything works fine.

```
    EV3GyroSensor ev3GyroSensor = new EV3GyroSensor(SensorPort.S4);

    SampleProvider sampleProvider = ev3GyroSensor.getAngleAndRateMode();
    float[] sample = new float[sampleProvider.sampleSize()];

    sampleProvider.fetchSample(sample, 0);
    System.out.println(sample[0]);

    //I move the robot with my hand
    Delay.msDelay(3000);

    sampleProvider.fetchSample(sample, 0);
    System.out.println(sample[0]);

    ev3GyroSensor.close();
```

Comment: If you can't get an answer here, you might try robotics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

try using only angle mode, from my experience, angle and rate mode doesn't always work correctly.
There is also a possibility that you are reading the rate from the sample, but I'm not really sure.